# Child process and parent process alternating

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe

I am trying to do a problem that says: Implement biderectional communication using one pipe by sycronizing the communication using two semaphores. I have been trying for a while now but to no luck. The output should be:

```
parent: a
child: b
parent: c
child: d
.....
```

but my program only prints:

```
parent:a 
child: b
```

and then it stops. I would love some help with this. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fdP2C[2];
    char c = 0;
    int i;
    sem_t parent_sem, child_sem;

    if (pipe(fdP2C) != 0) {
        perror("Could not create pipes");
        return 1;
    }

    sem_init(&parent_sem, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&child_sem, 0, 0);

    if (fork() != 0) {
        // Parent process
        close(fdP2C[0]);
        c = 'a';

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //sem_post(&child_sem);
            //sem_wait(&parent_sem);
            write(fdP2C[1], &c, sizeof(c));
            read(fdP2C[1], &c, sizeof(c));
            sem_wait(&parent_sem);
            printf("Parent: %c\n", c);
            c++;
            sem_post(&child_sem);

        }

        close(fdP2C[1]);
        wait(NULL);
    } else {
        // Child process
        close(fdP2C[1]);

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //sem_wait(&child_sem);
            sem_post(&parent_sem);
            write(fdP2C[0], &c, sizeof(c));
            read(fdP2C[0], &c, sizeof(c));

            c++;
            //sem_post(&parent_sem);
            printf("Child: %c\n", c);
            //sem_post(&parent_sem);
            //sem_wait(&child_sem);
            sem_post(&parent_sem);
            sem_wait(&child_sem);
        }

        close(fdP2C[0]);
    }

    sem_destroy(&parent_sem);
    sem_destroy(&child_sem);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it under a debugger to see where they're getting stuck? You probably have a deadlock because both the parent and child are waiting for the other to do something.

Comment: Pipe is a unidirectional data channel. You can't write to read end in parent and read from write end in child.

Comment: See [formatting code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: To fix the problem @dimich pointed out, create two pipes: `fdP2C` and `fdC2P`

Comment: the problem says i can only use one pipe. I just learned processes and pipes 3 weeks ago and i dont fully understand the way they work yet so i am sorry if wrote something stupid

Comment: i will try to find the deadlock

Comment: This may make it easier to see part of the problem: Define `enum { P_RD = 0, P_WR = 1 };` and then only use `fdP2C[P_RD]` to read from the pipe and `fdP2C[P_WR]` to write to the pipe.

Comment: As @TedLyngmo noted, you can use both pipe descriptors in both processes. Don't close() read end in parent and write end in child but use them for transfer data from child to parent as well as from parent to child.

Answer (score 2):

If you want parent and child processes to access the same (unnamed) semaphores, as apparently you do, two things are required:

1. The semaphores must reside in shared memory.
2. The semaphores must be initialized with the `pshared` option.

Neither of those criteria being satisfied in your program, your parent and child processes are using separate, independent semaphores.  That is why you are deadlocking.

Unnamed semaphores have the advantage that they exist only in memory, so it is fairly easy control access to them and to clean them up when they are no longer needed.  If you want to avoid the complications of shared memory, however, then you have the alternative of using *named* semaphores, which you would obtain access to via `sem_open()` instead of `sem_init()`.  These persist until unlinked via `sem_unlink()`, but it is safe to unlink them while the processes involved are still using them, as long as you wait until all processes that need them have, in fact, opened them.

---

As a separate matter, you are using the pipe incorrectly.  For example, here:

> ```
>             write(fdP2C[1], &c, sizeof(c));
>             read(fdP2C[1], &c, sizeof(c));
> ```

... the parent writes to the write end of the pipe, which is fine, but then it attempts to *read* from the write end of the pipe, which is wrong.  The child does the opposite: both writes to and reads from the read end.

Instead, each process must perform its writes on the write end of the pipe, and perform its reads on the read end of the pipe.  HOWEVER, for each one to avoid reading back its own message, it must perform an appropriate semaphore wait between writing and reading.  Of course, those waits must be paired with corresponding posts, at appropriate times, by the other process.